Why is self-representation vastly considered bad and wrong?
Why is self-representation vastly considered bad and wrong?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

canada
A person who is fit to stand trial can always choose to self-represent. Counsel cannot be forced upon them.
While a court can appoint an amicus to assist the court, that amicus's duty is to the court, not to the accused. And the court "may not appoint amicus with functions that would interfere with the right of the accused to represent themselves." R. v. Kahsai, 2023 SCC 20.
